# Shift timing event from GTAG to GTM

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, gtag.js

I've had trouble recreating a gtag event in Tag Manager, specifically one that accounts for user time on site, especially if a single page session. NOTE: we stopped using gtag before we implemented GTM, so there would be no double counting issues.

In tag manager, I created an event that used a trigger group that has a timing trigger (set to fire infinitely) and a scroll depth trigger. The tag worked in debug / preview mode on GTM. However, our analytics showed our average session duration fell by more than 60% as soon as we shifted to Tag Manager.

How might I recreate the following gtag event in Tag Manager? Or is the gtag code flawed somehow and is inaccurately counting session timing?

```
{ % if isSummaryPage or isMapPage or isStrategyPage %} 
< script >
  try {
    function timer15() {
      gtag('event', '15-30 seconds on page', {
        'event_category': 'TimeOnPage'
      });
    }

    function timer31() {
      gtag('event', '31-60 seconds on page', {
        'event_category': 'TimeOnPage'
      });
    }

    function timer61() {
      gtag('event', '1-3 minutes on page', {
        'event_category': 'TimeOnPage'
      });
    }

    function timer181() {
      gtag('event', '3-10 minutes on page', {
        'event_category': 'TimeOnPage'
      });
    }

    function timer601() {
      gtag('event', '10+ minutes on page', {
        'event_category': 'TimeOnPage'
      });
    }
    setTimeout(timer15, 15000);
    setTimeout(timer31, 31000);
    setTimeout(timer61, 61000);
    setTimeout(timer181, 181000);
    setTimeout(timer601, 601000);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('gtag() wasnt initialized correctly. Err:', e)
  }
```

Comment: Did you try to use a timer trigger?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Trigger Type, like this (the image below is only an example):

[image]

You can find it in: `Triggers > New > Trigger Configuration > Timer`

Just define the values ​​and apply the trigger to a Google Analytics event tag.
To simplify you can more than one time trigger and associate them to different events with the different values ​​you need.

Comment: Thanks so much for following up, Michele! In May 2021 we shifted to GTM. We created:
1. A timer trigger (as you recommended) with limit=1. We saw many single page sessions recorded as 10 seconds but they were much longer. We shifted to unlimited.
2. Scroll depth trigger (in px). Hours-long sessions were triggered without any pageviews, so we needed this. 

We implemented those triggers; however, our session length declined 50% compared to our gtag.js code. We shifted back, and session lengths look normal. Was GTM more accurate or gtag? Did we do something wrong with GTM? Thoughts?